# How do I modify this PyTorch convolutional neural network to accept a 64 x 64 image and properly output predictions?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I took this convolutional neural network (CNN) from [here](https://gist.github.com/johnolafenwa/96b3322aabb61d4d36fd870a77f02aa3). It accepts 32 x 32 images and defaults to 10 classes. However, I have 64 x 64 images with 500 classes. When I pass in 64 x 64 images (batch size held constant at 32), I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (128) to match target batch_size (32).
```

The stack trace starts at the line `loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)`. The `outputs.shape` is `[128, 500]` and the `labels.shape` is `[32]`.

The code is listed here for completeness.

```
class Unit(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_channels,out_channels):
        super(Unit,self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels,kernel_size=3,out_channels=out_channels,stride=1,padding=1)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=out_channels)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self,input):
        output = self.conv(input)
        output = self.bn(output)
        output = self.relu(output)
        return output

class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_classes=10):
        super(SimpleNet,self).__init__()

        self.unit1 = Unit(in_channels=3,out_channels=32)
        self.unit2 = Unit(in_channels=32, out_channels=32)
        self.unit3 = Unit(in_channels=32, out_channels=32)

        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

        self.unit4 = Unit(in_channels=32, out_channels=64)
        self.unit5 = Unit(in_channels=64, out_channels=64)
        self.unit6 = Unit(in_channels=64, out_channels=64)
        self.unit7 = Unit(in_channels=64, out_channels=64)

        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

        self.unit8 = Unit(in_channels=64, out_channels=128)
        self.unit9 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)
        self.unit10 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)
        self.unit11 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)

        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)

        self.unit12 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)
        self.unit13 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)
        self.unit14 = Unit(in_channels=128, out_channels=128)

        self.avgpool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=4)

        self.net = nn.Sequential(self.unit1, self.unit2, self.unit3, self.pool1, self.unit4, self.unit5, self.unit6
                                 ,self.unit7, self.pool2, self.unit8, self.unit9, self.unit10, self.unit11, self.pool3,
                                 self.unit12, self.unit13, self.unit14, self.avgpool)

        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=128,out_features=num_classes)

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.net(input)
        output = output.view(-1,128)
        output = self.fc(output)
        return output
```

Any ideas on how to modify this CNN to accept and properly return outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is an incompatible reshape (view) at the end.

You're using a sort of "flattening" at the end, which is different from a "global pooling". Both are valid for CNNs, but only the global poolings are compatible with any image size.

### The flattened net (your case)

In your case, with a flatten, you need to keep track of all image dimensions in order to know how to reshape at the end.

So:

- Enter with 64x64
- Pool1 to 32x32
- Pool2 to 16x16
- Pool3 to 8x8
- AvgPool to 2x2

Then, at the end you've got a shape of `(batch, 128, 2, 2)`. Four times the final number if the image were 32x32.

Then, your final reshape should be `output = output.view(-1,128*2*2)`.

This is a different net with a different classification layer, though, because `in_features=512`.

### The global pooling net

On the other hand, you could use the same model, same layers and same weights for any image size >= 32 if you replace the last pooling with a global pooling:

```
def flatChannels(x):
    size = x.size()
    return x.view(size[0],size[1],size[2]*size[3])

def globalAvgPool2D(x):        
    return flatChannels(x).mean(dim=-1)

def globalMaxPool2D(x):
    return flatChannels(x).max(dim=-1)
```

The ending of the model:

```
    #removed the pool from here to put it in forward
    self.net = nn.Sequential(self.unit1, self.unit2, self.unit3, self.pool1, self.unit4, 
                             self.unit5, self.unit6, self.unit7, self.pool2, self.unit8, 
                             self.unit9, self.unit10, self.unit11, self.pool3, 
                             self.unit12, self.unit13, self.unit14)

    self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=128,out_features=num_classes)


def forward(self, input):
    output = self.net(input)
    output = globalAvgPool2D(output) #or globalMaxPool2D
    output = self.fc(output)
    return output
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use transforms module before trainig neural network (here is the link https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html).

You have a few options:

1. transforms.Resize(32),
2. transforms.ResizedCrop(32) - most preferable, because you can augment your data and prevent overfitting in some respect via this way.
3. transforms.CenterCrop(32), etc.

Moreover, you could compose transforms objects into one object via transforms.Compose).

Enjoy.

PS. Of course, you can refactor your Neural Network architecture, enabling it to take images of size 64 x 64.

Comment: Yes, it's the "refactoring" of the CNN that I want information about. At 32x32, the images are in such poor resolution/quality, the CNN learns nothing. I am trying to do it for 64x64 and possibly even 128x128 (the last image size produces decent quality that feels like the classification might work). I do NOT want to resize from 64x64 to 32x32.